# iOS Collection view not rendering cells in correct columns

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am rendering a collection view in which I want to render items in 3 columns.
If I have 4 items, it is rendering like this -

```
|   1  |   2   |  3   |
|      |   4   |      |
```

looking to achieve this

```
|   1  |   2   |  3   |
|   4  |       |      |
```

Also for 2 items - rendering like below

```
|   1  |      |  2   |
```

Here is how my layout logic looks like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad || UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 0
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
    return CGSize(width: dim - CGFloat(1.0), height: CGFloat(110))

  } else {
    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 2
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 0
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
    return CGSize(width: dim - CGFloat(1.0), height: CGFloat(110))
  }
 }
```

How can the items be re-arranged properly. Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You are using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`??

Comment: You need to use a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. The rendering you are witnessing is the default one. The issue is "my layout logic looks like", that's not entirely true. That's part of your layout logic, especially the part about the size, but not the part about the origines (CGPoint(origin) + CGSize gives CGRect), and that's your issue, so use a custom layout.

Comment: I am using flow layout.

Comment: @icodes you need some custom layout like **SquareMosaicLayout**